# Which standard is used to inspect stranded cables secured to PCBA with RTV?

Tags: pcb-assembly, ipc

Does some one know what standard can be use for quality inspection on a PCBA that have stranded wires soldered and fixed with RTV?

I check the IPC-A-610 Rev E and the most similar criteria, is in the section 7.2.2, but it is for Axial/Radial components.

This is the comment from the IPC standard:

> On an unsleeved vertically mounted component there are a minimum of 2 beads of staking material for at least 25% of its length (L), and 25% of its circumference. Adhesion to the mounting surface is evident.

I might be able to adapt the criteria to stranded wires, but I am working in a medical industry and a standard is preferred, otherwise I'll have to validate it.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Is soldering and securing with RTV the only option? Using a connector is out of the question? Or using PCB features such as holes for stain relief instead of RTV? I realize this doesn't answer your question. I am just curious. I hate using RTV on PCBA's.